# Ruby: doesn't allow to put whitespace after 'yield'

Tags: ruby, yield, parentheses

Is there some reason for the whitespace not being allowed after **yield** keyword if the arguments I pass are in parentheses? This code will gather a mistake:

```
def who_says_what
yield ("rose","yay")
end
who_says_what {|flower,speech| puts "#{flower} says #{speech}"}
```

While this code can have as many whitespaces after yield as I'd like to:

```
def who_says_what
yield "rose","yay"
end
who_says_what {|flower,speech| puts "#{flower} says #{speech}"}
```

Comment: It seems general method argument list rule applied.

Comment: This is how the method is invoked in ruby and same as def add 4,5 instead of def add(4,5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `yield` keyword is behaving no differently from the method invocation syntax. If you have a space between a method name and the parentheses containing the method's arguments, the interpreter parses the parentheses as passing a single argument that is the result of the expression inside of the parentheses.

Take this for example:

```
def foo
    yield('foo', 'bar')
end

foo {|x, y| print x, y }
```

The above outputs 'foobar' as expected.

```
def foo
    yield ('foo', 'bar')
end

foo {|x, y| print x, y }
```

Because parentheses for invoking a method are optional and are expected to immediately follow the name (or `yield` keyword in this case), here the block is being called with only one argument: the expression `('foo', 'bar')`.

However, a comma is unexpected in this expression and you get the `SyntaxError` exception.  You can replicate the same error more simply by trying to evaluate the expression `('foo', 'bar')` in `irb`.

This is legal:

```
def foo
    yield ('foobar')
end

foo {|x| puts x }
```

That correctly prints 'foobar' since the result of the expression `('foobar')` is `'foobar'`, and that is the argument passed to the block.

Likewise, this prints 4 and 8 as one would expect:

```
def foo
    yield (2+2), (4+4)
end

foo {|x, y| puts x; puts y }
```